# Create user defined function for excel generated via PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am new to PHPExcel 
I want to know that is it possible with PHPExcel to create user defined function for excel generated by PHPExcel? (output format .xlsx)

I have googled a log but could not found any helpful information.

if any other php API which fulfill this requirement please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: It is not possible to create Excel user-defined functions with PHPExcel

If you want to create a UDF in Excel from a PHP script, then your only option is to use [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) There are no other PHP libraries that support this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it becomes helpful to you.
Go to this site and click on the download button. 
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/
It contains some of the scripts which may help you to sort out problem.

Comment: Note that the PHPExcel code is now maintained on github (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) rather than on the old codeplex repository